# Create a List with simple title

Tags: list, title

I want to create a list with a very simple title but with a complete description.
This way I can have a very simple link (and internal reference), like:

```
/Lists/ListA/AllItems.aspx
```

The problem is that on the List's page SharePoint shows the List title, while I'd like to show the List description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you creating list from UI.

First you enter list name `ListA` like you did.

Then go to **list settings** click on **List name, description and navigation** and change **Name** to something more descriptive like `List for something`.

This will change display name of the list but url will remain the same (/Lists/ListA/AllItems.aspx)

;)

Comment: Yes.. It does the trick! 
Of course, I create the lists via CSOM, but I think I can find an escamotage like this in the code... First I create the "simple" list, then I change the title via CSOM...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not working for long with SharePoint yet, but one quick and dirty solution
would be to change the last part of your URL i guess.

There for go to Site Settings -> Look and feel -> Title description, and Logo
there at the bottom you will find "Web site Address" where you can change the last part of your URL.

Hope this'll do.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, in sharepoint all the list and libraries will display only the Title at the list page because title is a primary identification and description is a explanation of that title.

Whenever you mention a title while creating, it will create an URL based on your title and it not be changeable.

You can display the title on your list page using some script or code but it would not be recommended, because description is multi line text